# SQL query with variables in Postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql, plpgsql

I have an SQL query

```
SELECT c,d FROM tableX where a='str' AND b=var1 ;
```

I would like to substitute the var1 with a variable. I tried to use plpgsql.

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo (var1 integer) 
RETURNS TABLE (c integer, d varchar)  AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
 aa varchar = 'str';
BEGIN    
RETURN QUERY EXECUTE 
'SELECT c,d FROM tableX where a=aa AND b=@1' using var1;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

The error is

```
No operator matches the given name and argument type(s). You might need to add explicit type casts.
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First - the correct way to specify parameters is `$1`, not `@1`.

Second - you do not need dynamic sql to pass parameters to the query. Just write something like:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo (var1 integer) 
RETURNS TABLE (c integer, d varchar)  AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
 aa varchar = 'str';
BEGIN    
 RETURN QUERY SELECT c,d FROM tableX where a=aa AND b=var1;
END;
$BODY$
LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Comment: Using plpgsql is actually an overhead here. This could be done with a plain SQL function as well.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name I know. It is just an example.

Answer (score 2):

Just to practice in PostgreSQL, as a_horse_with_no_name said, it's possible to write function in plain SQL, here's my attempt:

```
CREATE FUNCTION foo1 (var1 integer) RETURNS TABLE(c int, d text) 
    AS $$ SELECT c,d FROM tableX where a='str' AND b=$1 $$
    LANGUAGE SQL;
```

[**SQL FIDDLE EXAMPLE**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!12/1ed29/1)

Answer (score 1):

Just try:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION foo (var1 integer) 
  RETURNS TABLE (c integer, d varchar)  AS
$BODY$
DECLARE 
  aa varchar = 'str';
BEGIN    
RETURN QUERY 
  SELECT c,d FROM tableX where a=aa AND b=var1;
END;
```